# Visual Studio 2010's Parameter List (Intellisence) not showing all parameters

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I resently upgraded to VS 2010 and I think I've come across a deal-breaker bug if I cannot get it fixed.   The problem is with the "Display Parameter Info" (ctrl-shift-space) feature that lists the parameters for the current method/function, bolding the current parameter your cursor is currently on.

The problem is that 2010 is not showing all parameters, it seems limited to showing only 38 or so parameters in a vertical list.  VS 2005 and 2008 both showed the full list of parameters (hundreds if nessesary in a box below the method you are working in.   The 2010 vertical list does not scroll when you get to the end of the list to show more parameters,  once you pass the 38th parameter you are blind, with no way to tell what parameter you are currently entering/editing.

Here are a couple of screenshots that illustrate what I'm talking about.

Visual Studio 2005/2008,  how it used to be: [VS2008 Parameter List](http://www.screencast.com/t/D0kv5hiZK8)

Visual Studio 2010, showing only the first 38: [VS2010 Parameter List](http://www.screencast.com/t/zpzNKM2q)

In the 2010 screenshot, once I move to the parameter after "VIPs" the same list shows, with none bolded and I can no longer make changes because I don't know where I am in the method.

**System info:**
Windows 7 64-bit
Intel i7 CPU
16 GB DDR3 Memory
Visual Studio 2010  with Service Pack 1

Does anyone know how to get this fixed? Thanks in advance for any help/comments!

-BlueSteel

Comment: 38 parameters?!  Have you considered using a data structure?

Comment: What kind of psychotic code base are you working in that has methods with more than 38 parameters?

Comment: They are database Insert/Update/etc methods that are auto generated  when you add a DataSet (.XSD) file to your project and then connect it to a SQL database. Some of the tables have many (40 -75) columns,  each parameter represents a column in the database.  This was the preferred MS way of doing things before Linq to SQL and Entity Framework came out.  Unfortunatly the DataSet/TableAdapter method is used widely and vastly throughout many of my companies projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [known issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/535143/vs-2010-release-candidate-intellisense-displays-truncated-view-for-method-parameters), I'm afraid. A fix [was considered](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vseditor/thread/e2f06f24-0b68-48f3-a8b3-c31948f6e168) for SP1 but obviously didn't make it in. No word on SP2 yet.

Comment: Thanks for the links to the issue I'll be watching it. Crazy that this still hasn't been fixed,  the issue status shows "Closed: Fixed" but it isn't doesn't look like it will be any time soon.  :|